# how to change the slide speed of a viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

The default speed is too fast, and I think it would affect the user experience.

In the gallery, we can override the onfling(), what's the solution in a viewpager?

Answer (score 0):

The speed is determined by the screen density and is a private variable. There is no way of changing it.

A solution would be to copy the source for the ViewPager and create your own class. You can then change the value to whatever you want. The variable is `mBaseLineFlingVelocity` and it gets set during `initViewPager()`.

Comment: where can i get the source code of ViewPager?

Comment: I assume you are using the Support Package (if not you should be) the source code for the ViewPager can be found there with the .jar and the examples.